# Convert a DataTable with only one cell to a string

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Any LINQ queries for Converting a `DataTable` with a single cell(Data table is having only one row and one column) to a `String'.

```
DataTable like this 
|  Name  |
-----------
|  Alice  |
```

Would be great if there is already a way of doing this. Thanks

Comment: I don't think Linq's the right answer here. if you're sure the DataTable has at least one row and one column, then `dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()` will retrieve it. If this particular query only ever returns one value, consider using ExecuteScalar() on your DbCommand instead of setting up a DataTable.

Comment: Linq is definitely the wrong way to go here, `ExecuteScalar` is designed to get only one value, and `.ToString()` turns an object into a string. If you have the datatable already and are not able to change to a scalar, you access `Rows[0][0]` The first (only) column in the first (only) row and get the string from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why LINQ?

```
string firstName = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("Name"); // or Field<string>(0)
```

If it must be LINQ:

```
string firstName = table.AsEnumerable().First().Field<string>("Name");
```

If you only select one field from database you should better not use a `DataTable`:

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection("connectring"))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM Table WHERE Id = @Id", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1234; 
    con.Open();
    string name = (string) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```